# Obstructions for existence of a Riemannian metric such that a given function is harmonic

Tags: riemannian-geometry, laplacian, harmonic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a  smooth  function. What type of  obstructions exist for  existence of  a  Riemannian metric   $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$  such  that $f$  is  a  harmonic  function. In  particular is the  following  condition  sufficient for  existence of  such  Riemannian metric $g$?:

For  every compact  codimension one  submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$   with normal vector  field $N$, the function $\nabla f.N$  change  signe on $M$.

Comment: Well, besides the maximum principle, there exist uniqueness theorems (like you cannot have all derivatives zero at a point), at least if "smooth" means "$C^\infty$".

Comment: In three or more dimensions the problem is equivalent with finding a positive definite matrix function $\gamma$ so that $\text{div}(\gamma\nabla f)=0$, if that is more convenient to work with. There is also a special case you might want to check first: If $\nabla f$ has no zeros, your sign changing condition is true. Is the claim true for such functions?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta  thank you for your comment. Regarding your last statement: in this case, we have a submersion so a foliation. This situation remind me the following statement which I heard many years ago: every foliation of the plane can be considered as level sets of  a harmonic function(a global result!) I do not remember the reference.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta  why dim. 2 is an exception?

Comment: This has to do with conformal invariance of the Laplacian in dimension two. If you change the metric conformally, the harmonic functions are the same. If you look at the local coordinate formula for the Laplace-Beltrami operator, you'll see that the matrix $\gamma$ that appears between the derivatives can be anything in other dimensions but has to have determinant one in dimension two.